# Testing the bot in Web Chat does not return the reply. Checked many possibles issues

Tags: azure, botframework

Please,
I am testing my hello world bot in Azure web chat. This bot was ok in bot emulator, and was published (from BB SDK V4) without any issue. I`m already checked:

- messaging endpoint url.
- app ID
- app password
- name of app

I just receive a `couldn`t send retry` message.
What can be going on with my IcidHelloWorldBot? Any other information which I can post here?

Comment: does it work locally with appID and password? check this article as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: Thanks for helping. I went into the article but I think the Echo Bot V4 template does not have the appsettings.config file. Could you just say where they should be?

Comment: in the root of the project

Comment: What does the developer console say? That's the best way to see what's going on when you use 'Test in Web Chat'.

Comment: Guys I also do not know what it means `the root of the project`. I checked entire folder...So I just decided to redo all procedure again. I found an error, a small " ' " which bot emulator and publishing at https address did not accused (or maybe something else). Fact is, now bot functions correctly at Web Chat :)